# PHP Notice:what is the pro

Tags: php

I've been getting this error. Any fix??

PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in line 402

```
if ($argv[1] == '--cover')
{
    $Modules = new Modules;
    $Modules->cover();
    die();
}
```

The line is `if ($argv[1] == '--cover')`

Comment: Try to print_r($argv) to see what does the result

Answer (score 1):

An offset is undefined if it doesn't exist in the array.
Try this:

```
if(isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == '--cover'){
$Modules = new Modules;
$Modules->cover();
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the $argv[1] is **undefined or null.** Make **sure** this variable is **properly assign** or have a value **before making a condition**.

using `print_r($argv);` before making a condition will help you if the variable have a value or not.